Convergence of conditional expectations in $L_p$ for non-negative adapted processes
Given an adapted processes $(X_n, \mathscr{F}_n)$ that satisfies $X_n \geq 0$ for all $n > 0$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} X_n = 1$, can we conclude that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \mathbb{E}(X_n | \mathscr{F}_{n-1})$ converges in any $L_p$?

English-speaking mathematicians use the word "any" too much. In normal English, "Can we conclude this converges in any $L_p$?" can be construed as "Is there any $L_p$ in which we can conclude this converges?", which makes "any" an existential quantifier. But it might also mean "Is it true that in any $L_p,$ no matter which one, we can conclude this converges?", which makes "any" a universal quantifier. Just writing "every" (if that's what is meant) would not be in the least ambiguous.

@MichaelHardy I have to agree given that I was also concerned about the ambiguity.

Yes. In fact, we even have convergence a.s. The process $Y_n := \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E[X_i|\mathcal F_{i-1}]$ is a uniformly integrable submartingale (to see this, use the fact that $X_i$ are uniformly integrable, and the tower property of conditional expectation). So it converges a.s. and in every $L^p$ by the  submartingale convergence theorem.

Convergence holds in any $L^p$ for $p\geqslant 1$. By Theorem III.4.3 page 106 in
Garsia, Adriano M.
Martingale inequalities: Seminar notes on recent progress. Math. Lecture Note Ser.
W. A. Benjamin, Inc., Reading, Mass.-London-Amsterdam, 1973. viii+184 pp.
the inequality
$$
\mathbb E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb E\left[Z_i\mid\mathcal F_{i-1}\right]\right)^p\right]\leqslant p^{p+1}\mathbb E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i\right)^p\right]
$$
holds for any $p\geqslant 1$, any non-negative random variables $Z_i$ and any increasing collection of $\sigma$-algebra $(\mathcal F_i)$.
Applying this for fixed $M<N$ to $Z_i=0$ if $i\leqslant M-1$ and $Z_i=X_i$ otherwise gives
$$
\mathbb E\left[\left(\sum_{i=M}^N\mathbb E\left[X_i\mid\mathcal F_{i-1}\right]\right)^p\right]\leqslant p^{p+1}\mathbb E\left[\left(\sum_{i=M}^N X_i\right)^p\right]
$$
and using the assumption $\sum_i X_i\leqslant 1$ gives
$$
\mathbb E\left[\left(\sum_{i=M}^N\mathbb E\left[X_i\mid\mathcal F_{i-1}\right]\right)^p\right]\leqslant p^{p+1}\mathbb E\left[ \sum_{i=M}^N X_i \right].
$$
By monotone convergence theorem, $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb E[X_i]$ converges  hence the sequence $\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E\left[X_i\mid\mathcal F_{i-1}\right]\right)$ is Cauchy in $L^p$.
